# get submit button id

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Inside asp.net form I have few dynamically generated buttons, all of this buttons submit a form, is there a way to get which button was submit the form in page load event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sender` argument to the handler contains a reference to the control which raised the event.

```
private void MyClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button theButton = (Button)sender;
    ...
}
```

**Edit:** Wait, in the Load event? That's a little tricker. One thing I can think of is this: The Request's Form collection will contain a key/value for the submitting button, but not for the others. So you can do something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button theButton = null;
    if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("button1"))
        theButton = button1;
    else if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("button2"))
        theButton = button2;
    ...
}
```

Not very elegant, but you get the idea..

Comment: yea I know,but I need it on page load, event is called after page load

Comment: are you sure buttons exists in request.forms collection ?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt : Sorry I don't ask you my previous question. Buttons are not posted to server in Request.Forms collection. I just  wanted to inform Tor.

Comment: @Canavar: Not all of them, no, but the submitting one is. The key is the ID, and the value is the text. I tested my code. Did you?

Comment: And what's with the downvote, I answered the question, didn't I (whine whine ;-)?

Comment: Just a clarification, the NAME of the submitting button appears in keys collection, rather than its id.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
    string id = "";
    foreach (string key in Request.Params.AllKeys) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params[key]) && Request.Params[key].Equals("Click"))
            id = key;
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
        Control myControl = FindControl(id);
        // Some code with myControl
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work if your code is inside a user control:

```
Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("btnSave") ...
```

Instead you can try this:

```
if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(p => p.Contains("btnSave")).Count() > 0)
{
    // btnSave was clicked, your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if (this.Page.Request.Form[this.btnSave.ClientID.Replace("_", "$")] != null) {

}
```

Comment: it will allways return true if the button on the form @patrick

Comment: i have 3 buttons on my form and it only appears in the request if I click it.
But an other option is to use a LinkButton and then it fills the __EVENTTARGET and you could use something like:
`this.Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Contains("btnSave")`

Answer (score 0):

please try this code in page load event

```
string eventtriggeredCategory = Request.Form["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCategory"];
```

if eventtriggeredCategory is returning any value its fired the event of ddlCategory

this is works fine for me

Thanks 
Jidhu

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` will give you the button that fired the postback

Answer (score -2):

Use [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) property to determine which button submits the form.

**Edit :** I just realized, you said you need this at PageLoad, this works only for Click server side event, not for PageLoad.

Comment: And anyway, the CommandArgument does not contain a reference to the button, only the value for CommandArgument set in the button.

Comment: ok, the when programmer dynamically generates the button, he can set the commandargument parameter as well, right ?

Comment: Oh yes, and that is probably a better idea if you ask me.